# Why am I getting "undefined reference to vtable..." errors when linking this Qt 5.0 application?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

I've got a relatively simple Qt 5.0 project that uses CMake 2.8.9:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
project(hello-world)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
qt5_wrap_ui(hello-world_UI MainWindow.ui)

add_executable(hello-world MainWindow.cpp main.cpp ${hello-world_UI})
qt5_use_modules(hello-world Widgets)
```

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:

        MainWindow();
        virtual ~MainWindow();

    private:

        Ui::MainWindow * const ui;
};

#endif // CMAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
    : ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow win;
    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The project also includes a `.ui` file created with Qt Creator 2.6.1 (MainWindow.ui).

When I attempt to build the file with `g++` on Linux, I receive the following errors:

```
CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o: In function `MainWindow::MainWindow()':
MainWindow.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
MainWindow.cpp:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o: In function `MainWindow::~MainWindow()':
MainWindow.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
MainWindow.cpp:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What could possibly be causing this sort of error? I recently switched to CMake from `qmake` and I never remember running into this much trouble getting a trivial example to compile. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** here is the command being used to link everything:

```
/usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/main.cpp.o -o hello-world -rdynamic
/usr/local/Qt-5.0.0/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.0.0
/usr/local/Qt-5.0.0/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.0.0
/usr/local/Qt-5.0.0/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.0.0 
-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Qt-5.0.0/lib
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out I forgot:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
```

At the top of the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: I do have set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) but I still see the same error as you were seeing. Also, my link command is the same as yours. Can you please help?

Comment: Also, the moc file "nova_app_automoc.cpp" generated for the target "nova_app" has this in it:                                          /* This file is autogenerated, do not edit*/
enum some_compilers { need_more_than_nothing };

Comment: I'm having almost the exact same problem, yet I have set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) already in my CMakeLists.txt and yet I still get the problem!!

Comment: @AdamMiller I know this is old but in case somebody else is having the same issue, cmake needs to know where to find the headers. Before I GLOBed all my headers in with my sources, I was getting the issue you had. By verbose building I could see automoc was generating nothing.

Comment: @regomodo, You are a lifesaver! I forgot to add my header files to the CMake `add_library` function. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this for a long time using all the hints published here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

And here

https://www.kdab.com/using-cmake-with-qt-5/

What I had to do was specify things in the right order. For example, the following is the top of my CMakeLists.txt. Note that the two CMAKE set directives come before add_executable. Once I did this, I was able to link without undefined symbols and vtable references. I just thought I'd post this for the benefit of others.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

set (CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
add_executable(FHSpectrumSensor wideband_seq_spectrum_sensor.cpp sensor.cpp   gui.cpp ${gui_SRC})
```

Later in the CMakeLists.txt I have the following:

```
 find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
 find_package(Qt5Charts REQUIRED)
 find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)

 qt5_use_modules(FHSpectrumSensor Widgets Charts)
 qt5_wrap_cpp(gui_SRC gui.h gui.cpp)
```

That did the trick.

Comment: Worked for me thanks ! the problem was solved with `qt5_wrap_cpp(gui_SRC gui.h gui.cpp)`. actually instead of gui.cpp I added .h files and that was the problem, now I changed them to .cpp files and problem solved thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this problem yesterday and the above mentioned answers did't help. I already used `set (CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` and also `qt5_wrap_cpp`.

I tried to remember what I did, because I had a working version but it stopped working after "some" changes. I finally remembered that I tried to split the include files into a separate directory hierarchy. After reverting that and putting the include files back into the `CMakeLists.txt` it worked again. I sure don't know why, and I would like to know what went wrong, but I settled now for keeping the includes near the `cpp` files.

```
set(SOURCES
    buffer.h
    ITVSet.h
    MainWindow.h
    MainWindow.cpp
    TVSet.h
    TVSet.cpp
)
```

Comment: when you added `MainWindow.h` to SOURCES or you can split to project_HEADERS , then the header is included in the build and moc files are generated for that header