# undefined function during cmake linking local file

Tags: c++, qt, linker, cmake

I'm trying to compile a small Qt example to an executable (with the test.cpp containg main) and later add support for compiling the non-test.cpp code to its own library.  I was using qmake, but now I'm trying to use cmake following the example [here](http://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects).  Unfortunately, I'm getting a linking error.  Looks like the constructors, which I define in the cpp files that are compiling aren't being found at link time.

```
$ make
Linking CXX executable test
CMakeFiles/test.dir/attribute_editor.cpp.o: In function `AttributeEditor::AttributeEditor(QWidget*)':
attribute_editor.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `vtable for AttributeEditor'
CMakeFiles/test.dir/bindable.cpp.o: In function `Bindable::Bindable(QObject*)':
bindable.cpp:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `vtable for Bindable'
CMakeFiles/test.dir/bindable.cpp.o: In function `AttributeObject::AttributeObject()':
bindable.cpp:(.text._ZN15AttributeObjectC2Ev[_ZN15AttributeObjectC5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `vtable for AttributeObject'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is my cmake file...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# http://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects

PROJECT(qattrs)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)
SET(QT_USE_QTSCRIPT TRUE)

SET(qattrs_SOURCES test.cpp attribute_editor.cpp bindable.cpp)
SET(qattrs_HEADERS bindable.h attribute_editor.h)

QT4_WRAP_CPP(qattrs_HEADERS_MOC ${qattrs_HEADERS})

INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(test ${qattrs_SOURCES} ${qattrs_HEADER_MOC})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

I know very little about cmake, but I assume it's not including the .o files during linking.

The entire code (five or six files) is on [github](https://github.com/strattonbrazil/qattrs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on another question.  It wasn't in the example Qt doc, but I just needed to set another environment variable.

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

[Why am I getting "undefined reference to vtable..." errors when linking this Qt 5.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015792/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-vtable-errors-when-linking-this-qt)

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find a vtable for something - this means it is looking for the entries a type would put in it's vtable if it existed, because it is a linker. (It is not talking about a type lacking a vtable at runtime because that'd make no sense at all, I don't even like that sentence)

Somewhere you have a pure-virtual method you have never defined.

That code is REALLY hard to read and reading it I couldn't see any virtuals even in bindable.h, this means there's a pure virtual function in the parent class and you never implement it, that is your error.

Well more specifically you never implement 3 of them.

*I'd feel bad for not saying:* wxWidgets FTW :P