# Qt5 with CMake - vtable error while AUTOMOC is ON

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, vtable

I am trying to run simple Calculator example of Qt5 tutorials using CMake. The error I got is

```
[ 25%] Automatic moc and uic for target calculator
[ 25%] Built target calculator_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target calculator
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable calculator
CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `Calculator::Calculator(QWidget*)'
CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Calculator::~Calculator()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN10CalculatorD2Ev[_ZN10CalculatorD5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for Calculator'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN10CalculatorD2Ev[_ZN10CalculatorD5Ev]+0x21): undefined reference to `vtable for Calculator'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/build.make:123: recipe for target 'calculator' failed
make[3]: *** [calculator] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'calculator' failed
make: *** [calculator] Error 2
```

Then I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015792/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-vtable-errors-when-linking-this-qt?noredirect=1&lq=1#) and set CMAKE_AUTOMOC to ON, but it didn't help. It seems it's a basic CMakeLists.txt mistake but I cannot overcome for days.

Here are my files:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Tell CMake to create the calculator executable
add_executable(calculator main.cpp)

project(calculator)

SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{HOME}/software/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(calculator Qt5::Widgets)
```

main.cpp

```
 #include <QApplication>    
 #include "calculator.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     Calculator calc;

     calc.show();
     return app.exec();
 }
```

calculator.h

```
 #ifndef CALCULATOR_H
 #define CALCULATOR_H    
 #include <QWidget>

 class Calculator : public QWidget
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     Calculator(QWidget *parent = 0);
 };

 #endif
```

calculator.cpp

```
 #include <QtGui>    
 #include <math.h>    
 #include "calculator.h"

 Calculator::Calculator(QWidget *parent)
     : QWidget(parent)
 {
     QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
     setWindowTitle(tr("Calculator"));
 }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Make a minimal small example showing the problem. Don't just copy everything here.

Comment: I've uploaded the minimal small example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This line in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(calculator main.cpp) #calculator.cpp button.cpp)
```

Possibly you are not aware of this, but the `#` specifies a comment. As a result cmake is not set up to make `calculator.cpp` or `button.cpp` compiled or linked into your executable.